# Close Realm instance after execution finishes

Tags: android, realm

I want to close my Realm instance in `executeTransactionAsync` after execution finished. Reason is that my applications main thread keeps on freezing, I think the reason for it is that the background realm instance is not being closed after execution finishes. See my code below:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        // Execute realm code
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(myData);
                        // Can I close the realm instance here without getting an 
                        // error? realm.close(); causes an error.
                    }
                }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.i("CB", "success");
                        // looks like I cannot access the execute Realm 
                        // instance here.
                        // Closing realm.getDefaultInstance does not change my issue
                    }
                }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error) {
                        Log.i("CB", "error - " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
```

Please see my comments. My application screen just turns black. Execution completes successfully and `onSuccess()` gets called, but I cannot access the `execute` realm instance to close it from here.

Do you have any suggestions as to what I can try? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

```
07-19 11:43:42.379 8146-8146/com.shortterminsurance.shortterm I/CB: success
07-19 11:43:43.258 8146-8152/com.shortterminsurance.shortterm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.234ms
07-19 11:43:43.266 8146-8156/com.shortterminsurance.shortterm I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 476307(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 512(10MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 33MB/55MB, paused 7.261ms total 163.497ms
07-19 11:43:44.131 8146-8156/com.shortterminsurance.shortterm I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 408160(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 459(15MB) LOS objects, 35% free, 35MB/55MB, paused 10.287ms total 147.823ms
07-19 11:43:44.834 8146-8152/com.shortterminsurance.shortterm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 103.676ms
07-19 11:43:44.848 8146-8156/com.shortterminsurance.shortterm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.424ms
```

This is my logcat after my onSuccess gets called. I think the background instance of realm in `execute` keeps running for some reason :(.

Comment: Wait which realm instance do you want to close? What are you referring to with `background instance`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I want to close the realm instance in `execute`. Will quickly edit my question with some more info

Comment: Do you mean the instance passed here `public void execute(Realm realm) {`?

Comment: (By the way, what version of Realm are you using?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The realm instance that is passed here

```
@Override
public void execute(Realm realm) {
```

is closed for you. You don't have to worry about closing it yourself.

If you check the source code for Realm.executeTransactionAsync(), you can find

```
bgRealm.beginTransaction();
try {
    transaction.execute(bgRealm);

    if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        bgRealm.commitTransaction(false, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // The bgRealm needs to be closed before post event to caller's handler to avoid
                // concurrency problem. eg.: User wants to delete Realm in the callbacks.
                // This will close Realm before sending REALM_CHANGED.
                bgRealm.close();
            }
        });
        transactionCommitted = true;
    }
}
...
```

So first it calls `.execute()` on your transaction, and after that it closed the realm instance it passed to you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a possibility:

```
            final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    // Execute realm code
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(myData);
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.i("CB", "success");
                    realm.close();
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    Log.i("CB", "error - " + error.getMessage());
                    realm.close();
                }
            });
        }
```

Although the **background realm** instance is closed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Castelijns said, executeTransactionAsync already closes realm, anyways, don't closing instance of realm don't cause UI block, but throws exception if you try to open a Realm instance, so you should have another problem

Comment: I would if I could. See the comments that I added, I cannot access the background realm instance in onSuccess / onError.

Comment: Tim Castelijns said executeTransactionAsync() already closes realm so you should have another problem

Answer (score 1):

```
final Realm realmFirstInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realmFirstInstance.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                // Execute realm code
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(myData);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.i("CB", "success");
                realmFirstInstance.close();
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.i("CB", "error - " + error.getMessage());
                realmFirstInstance.close();
            }
        });
    }
```

In addition for cleaner understanding: do not forget to close first realm instance. Because here "realmFirstInstance" and "realm" inside execute() method  - are two different objects.